Error in RAGAS: "embeddings must be set" when using answer_similarity in FastAPI
I'm developing a REST API using FastAPI, and I'm trying to calculate the similarity between answers using the RAGAS library. However, I encounter an error that says embeddings must be set.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from ragas.metrics import answer_similarity
# Import any other necessary modules from ragas

app = FastAPI()

class Query(BaseModel):
    question: str
    answer: str
    reference_answer: str

@app.post("/similarity/")
async def calculate_similarity(query: Query):
    try:
        # Calculation of answer_similarity using RAGAS
        similarity_score = answer_similarity(
            query.answer, 
            query.reference_answer, 
            question=query.question
        )
        return {"similarity_score": similarity_score}
    except AssertionError as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)


When I send a request to the /similarity/ endpoint, I get the following error:
AssertionError: embeddings must be set
Interestingly, when I use the answer_similarity function in a regular Python script, it works without any issues. I assume I need to initialize embeddings before using answer_similarity. However, I couldn't find any methods like load_embeddings in the RAGAS library documentation. How should I properly initialize the necessary embeddings or components required by answer_similarity?

Just removed async from calculate_similarity method after that it works properly

I would suggest having a look at this answer for more details on async/await in FastAPI.
